# How session works? Where to save the session value? How to increase session life time?

Tags: php, session, session-variables, session-timeout

How session works? Where to save the session value? How to increase session life time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sessions make HTTP a virtually stateful protocol, which in fact is stateless. Session data is client-specific but stored on the server side, usually a serialized array in a text file. (The behavior can be overridden in PHP using the session handlers, see [session_set_save_handler()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php).)

The server gives the client a cookie which contains an identifier ([session id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php)) which uniquely identifies that client. When an HTTP request is made, the cookie containing the session id is sent along with it, and the server locates the client's session data and loads it, restoring the client's virtual *state*. (Sometimes the id is not sent via a cookie but as a GET parameter, but that's irrelevant.)

In PHP, you can access session state by using the [$_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) superglobal, after using [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) to create or resume a session.

Since HTTP is stateless, the server has no way of knowing when a client goes away (closes the browser window, goes out to buy some beverages...) Therefore, the only sensible thing to do is to measure the time that has passed since their last request, and assume them gone if it is over a threshold. This amount of time is called the "session timeout" or the "session lifetime." You can set its default value in the `php.ini` file or using the [ini_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) function. See the [section on session directives in php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

**How session work:** http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php

To increse session lifetime, use [`ini_set`](http://php.net/ini_set) function with `session.gc_maxlifetime` property:

```
 ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', '28800'); // Set maxlifetime to 4 hours
```

**Note:** If you have multiple pages on the same server, each using the session (the same or distinct named sessions, it doesn't matter), the *minimum* gc_maxlifetime of any of those scripts ends up being the effective lifetime of the session files.